# Azure Web Role Issues after SDK 2.7 update

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-sdk-.net

We have a a solution where we have a couple of webroles and a 3 worker roles. We deploy them using a cloudservice package. Now we recently updated it to Azure SDK 2.7. The package was successfully created and deployed.

After that we are facing all sorts fo problems.

1- Web site in Webrole are very slow to load for the first time. After a while they load but they seem to stuck every now and then for a long time.
2- Faceing shared access policy issues while working with encoding and saving media to storage.
3- I am running DBGView to look for errors and there are no exceptions. Except for the exception whcih I get in point 2.
4- Eventviewer has virtually nothing which could have helped me indetifying the problme.

Help from anyone who has updated their solution to Azure SDK 2.7 or anyone who face similar problem after updating the Azure SDK, wil be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to update to 2.7.1 to test out your solution?